# while loop during awaiting for async task

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous, async-await

I have a following problem. I have a synchronous .Save() action that takes quite a few minutes to complete. I cannot make it async (3rd party library), so to keep the UI responsive, I am using it all in `Task.Run()`.

I would like to report progress so that the users sees that *something* is happening - and I want to make it in the Status label - a simple and old school append and remove dots to string, sort of like
Wait.
Wait..
Wait...
Wait.

I don't know how to do it in a simple way - I thought of a `while` loop that would break once the Task ends, but it doesn't seem to work - either the UI is blocked or the status label does not update.

I tried a couple of things, for example:

```
bool done = false;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Exporter.DoLongSyncTask();
            }).ContinueWith(r => done = true);
            StatusLabel = ".";
            while (!done)
            {
                if (StatusLabel == "")
                    StatusLabel = ".";
                else if (StatusLabel == ".")
                    StatusLabel = "..";
                else if (StatusLabel == "..")
                    StatusLabel = "";
            }
```

(StatusLabel is a property with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented, it works OK)

and more complicated

```
private async Task<bool> DoTheWork()
        {

            await Task.Run(() => TheFile.Save());
            return true;
        }

            private string ReportProgress(string status)
        {
            if (status == ".")
                status = "..";
            else if (status == "..")
                status = "...";
            else if (status == "...")
                status = ".";
            MyProgress.Report(new InDesignExporterProgress { StatusInfo = status });
            return status;
        }

private string ReportProgress(string status)
{
    if (status == ".")
        status = "..";
    else if (status == "..")
        status = "...";
    else if (status == "...")
        status = ".";
    MyProgress.Report(new SomeProgressClass { StatusInfo = status });
    return status;
}
```

and the above are called from here

```
        bool done = false;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            done = DoTheWork().Result;
        });
        string status = ".";
        while (!done)
        {
            status = ReportProgress(status);
        }
```

So, what's the right way?

Comment: Lets try the second attempt to this question, as I suppose nobody would look at a fresh question with -3 votes anyway. Hope all the downvoters will now care to do something more constructive:)

Comment: You need to give your UI thread time to do its message pumping.  If you can't modify the original method to report progress, one option is to update status periodically based on a timer.

Comment: `done` variable that you can are using to signal two threads might not work because some time value is not immediately available to other thread.

Comment: @Bartosz Good time to read about *async/await*

Comment: @Eser - yes, you're probably right. I read a bit about this and I think I generally understand the concept, can you please point me to an article that could help with this issue?

Comment: Don't use that done variable, save the task that was created and use `task.IsCompleted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know if a task has been completed, check the value of the [IsCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Threading.Tasks.Task.IsCompleted) property.

```
while (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    // ...
}
```

But, for what I think you're trying to, I'd do something like this:

```
using (var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer())
{
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (StatusLabel == "")
            StatusLabel = ".";
        else if (StatusLabel == ".")
            StatusLabel = "..";
        else if (StatusLabel == "..")
            StatusLabel = "";
    };
    timer.Interval = 100;
    timer.Enabled = true;

    await Task.Run(() => Exporter.DoLongSyncTask);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are blocking your UI thread with the while loop since I guess it's running on that thread.

I suggest you try to change your while loop like this and the method signature to async Task

```
public async Task DoSomething(){
        bool done = false;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Exporter.DoLongSyncTask();
        }).ContinueWith(r => done = true);

        StatusLabel = ".";
        while (!done)
        {
            if (StatusLabel == "")
                StatusLabel = ".";
            else if (StatusLabel == ".")
                StatusLabel = "..";
            else if (StatusLabel == "..")
                StatusLabel = "";
            await Task.Delay(200);
        }
}
```

Comment: @Eser, can you please explain? what would be a better approach in this case?